# Accessing Spring beans in Runnable thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, executorservice

I need to access Spring beans(`featureService` and `uxService`) in my Runnable Thread below but am getting `null` value for `applicationContext` hence I couldnt get Spring beans inside the Runnable. I am wondering if its possible to access spring beans inside a runnable or not? if not please suggest me an alternative approach.

I am using `Spring 4.0.6` and `Java 8`

```
@Component
public class UserMenuUpdateTask implements Runnable, Serializable, ApplicationContextAware {


    private static final long    serialVersionUID = 3336518785505658027L;

    List<User>                   userNamesList;

    FeatureService               featureService;

    UXService uxService;

    private ApplicationContext   applicationContext;

    public UserMegaMenuUpdateTask() {}

    public UserMegaMenuUpdateTask(List<User> userNamesList) {
        this.userNamesList = userNamesList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (User user : userNamesList) {

                    featureService = (FeatureService) applicationContext.getBean("featureService");
                    uxService = (UxService) applicationContext.getBean("uxService");                    
                //.........
            }
        } catch (BaseApplicationException ex) {
            throw new BaseApplicationException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

    }
}
```

I am calling the runnable as below

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.execute(new UserMenuUpdateTask(activeUsers));
```

Comment: Are you calling `setApplicationContext()` before running it? You should probably also show us how you're using the Runnable.

Comment: @JiriTousek `setApplicationContext()` supposed to be called by `Spring`  container on application start up right..? I've updated the code for calling the Runnable

Comment: Only on the beans (objects) it knows about. You're creating a local instance in your code that Spring has no way of knowing about (Spring does not in fact use magic, even if it sometimes seems to :)

Answer (score 2):

`ApplicationContextAware` is an interface used by Spring to set its context into beans that Spring itself manages (knows about). Since you create the `UserMenuUpdateTask` yourself, Spring does not even know about the instance and cannot set the field.

If you don't need a new instance of your runnable for every call / every thread (i.e. if the `UserMenuUpdateTask` is stateless or thread-safe), you can let Spring manage it (through annotations or XML configuration) and use the Spring-instantiated instance in `ExecutorService.execute()`.

If a new instance of `UserMenuUpdateTask` is needed every time, you'll need to instead make the calling class `ApplicationContextAware` (assuming instance of it is managed by Spring), and set the pointer to application context in the `UserMenuUpdateTask` before giving it to the `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to store the `applicationContext` but ExecutorService creates a different Thread where no beans are managed and/or the beanContext does not find any beans.

Follow this [instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationContextAware interface works only when object is instantiated inside spring. When you do **new UserMenuUpdateTask(activeUsers)** spring doesn't know anything about this object hence it doesn't set applicationContext.

Write constructor without parameters, set scope to prototype and get this object from spring, at next line set activeUsers and it should work. Or set application by hands after object creation.

Also I would recommend you to change this lines

```
    for (User user : userNamesList) {

        featureService = (FeatureService) applicationContext.getBean("featureService");
        uxService = (UxService) applicationContext.getBean("uxService");                    
            //.........
        }
```

to

```
    featureService = (FeatureService) applicationContext.getBean("featureService");
    uxService = (UxService) applicationContext.getBean("uxService");      

    for (User user : userNamesList) {
        //.........
    }
```